# Improve OLE Automation stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ole

I have the following code sample that calls a Web API method:

```
DECLARE @Object AS int;
DECLARE @ResponSEText AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @Token AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @xmltest AS Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @hResult AS int
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255) 
DECLARE @LocationId varchar(25);

DECLARE @Body AS varchar(8000) = '{
  "UserName": "username",
  "Password": "password"
}'

--EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', 'https://urgentcargus.azure-api.net/api/LoginUser', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

DECLARE @len int
SET @len = len(@body)
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key','23cb2410112b4c01bc397bcda0d18487'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Ocp-Apim-Trace:true'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestBody', null, 'Body', @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'Send', null, @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responSEText', @ResponSEText OUTPUT

SELECT  @Token=@ResponSEText

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object

SET @Token  ='Bearer '+ REPLACE(@Token,'"','')
PRINT @Token
```

On my laptop (Win10, SQL Server 2017), I have a response of less than a second. However, the same code sample used on a customer's server (Windows Server 2012R2, SQL Server 2017) takes almost 21 seconds to get a response and even when it returns `NULL`.

Is there something that I'm missing? I'm guessing it has to do something related to the server settings and how it goes out, on the web. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the server going out through a proxy or directly? If it's directly without using any proxy, maybe adding one might help. I had the same issue with `Database Mail` from `SQL` and until setting a proxy and adding the port `SQL` is using, I wasn't able to send any e-mails.